# Mac OS X system log analysis for P2PInterface

Tags: macos

I am repeatedly defending myself from a determined hacker who usually installs keyloggers.

My system log now says I have P2PInterface attached. Is this a sign that I have been hacked (again)??

Answer (score 0):

`p2p0` is part of OS X’s built-in “AirDrop” and “AirPlay Solo” features.